# How to insert the rows vertically when using rowspan with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been working on this below code. Actually what i am doing is creating number of rows based on array values with the rowspan `2`.

```
var country = ['us', 'uk', 'fr', 'jp'];
var table = document.createElement('table');
table.style.border = '1px solid black';
document.body.appendChild(table);
for (var i = 0; i < country.length; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    table.appendChild(tr);
    var td_dmxn = document.createElement('td');
    td_dmxn.innerHTML = country[i];

    //adding rowspan here
    td_dmxn.rowSpan = '2';  
    td_dmxn.style.border = "1px solid black";
    tr.appendChild(td_dmxn);

}
```

when i am not using rowspan it works perfectly.
So my question is how to make the rows vertically adding when using `rowSpan`.Answer should be either in javascript or jquery. Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/htoniv/cb47puje/)

Comment: Vertically would be a column. Are you looking to span columns?

Comment: That would be like trying to drink two glasses of milk when you only have one glass. 4 `tr` cannot span 2 rows a piece when there are only 4 rows (you would need 8 rows).

Comment: Your table has only 1 column, it does not make sense applying `rowspan`.

Comment: yeah ofcourse i need 8 rows

Comment: @leo.fcx if it is not applicable for one column then why it is adding horizontally

Comment: Is there any way to do this.

Comment: @htoniv, I did not say that it is not applicable ... I said that it does not make sense. This is a good example in which it make sens to apply rowSpan: http://jsfiddle.net/cb47puje/2/

Comment: @leo.fcx is there any possible ways to stop coming horizontally. Because in mycase i am adding columns dynamically. so for first it is coming like this. please i need help.

Comment: @htoniv, you already have the answer ... don't use `rowSpan`

Answer (score 0):

> ...how to make the rows vertically adding when using rowSpan

change rowSpan value to "1". That's why it works fine when you are not using rowSpan since it defaults to 1.

Assuming you already tried it and if it doesn't give you what you are looking for then could you elaborate on what is desired. Also, is the rowspan set to "2" for any specific reason?

Comment: In my case i dynamically creating array values. So each time it creates new column and in each column rows contains varying `rowspan`

Comment: Okay. So from your for loop, the columns and rows have 1:1 relationship. In that case, rowspan makes very little sense. Its best used for a table with multiple columns.
http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/tables/index_famsupp_30.html  
What is the varying rowspan dependent on? Currently its hard-coded as 2.